# x509 certificate subject DN

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, keytool, subject

I need to create a self signed certificate with my own the Subject DN. Example: I want to set username in Subject DN. I will retrieve this information using

```
X509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName().
```

I was able to set the IssuserDN using -dname option of the keytool.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=MyApp ACES CA 2, OU=MyApp Public Sector, O=MyApp, C=US"  -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048 

getIssuerDN().getName()
getSubjectDN().getName()
```

prints following:

```
CN=MyApp ACES CA 2, OU=MyApp Public Sector, O=MyApp, C=US
CN=MyApp ACES CA 2, OU=MyApp Public Sector, O=MyApp, C=US
```

Not sure how to set the Subject DN using java keytool or openssl.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code, and point out where you are encountering the problem. Be sure to provide the exact error message at the point of failure.

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: In a self-signed certificate subject and issuer DN are always the same.

Comment: Thanks @Omikron. I thought there is a way to set Subject different than issuer in the self signed certificate.